# In jQuery, are there any function that similar to html() or text() but return the whole content of matched component?

Tags: jquery

For example, if the match is `<div class="class1">Hello world</div>`, I need to return

```
<div class="class1">Hello world</div>
```

not just "Hello world".

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no built-in function for getting the outerHTML, but you can use this:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return (s)
  ? this.before(s).remove()
  : jQuery("<p>").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

Then in your selector:
`$('.class1').outerHTML()` will give you what you are looking for.

[Source of function](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/)

Comment: +1 - Awesome, I've favourited this in case I need it some day.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [outerHTML plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml/).

Answer (score 3):

[@Jose Basilio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995760/in-jquery-are-there-any-function-that-similar-to-html-or-text-but-return-the/995796#995796) is great. But Brian Grinstead found a problem in this function when using IFrames: http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/jquery-outerhtml-snippet

Here I put together Jose's way for also **setting the outerHTML** with Brian's solution for **IFrames**:

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
    if (s) {
        return this.before(s).remove();
    } else {
        var doc = this[0] ? this[0].ownerDocument : document;
        return jQuery('<div>', doc).append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used .andSelf() with success:

http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/