# How to get html string of a child tag and parent tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

For example if I have HTML `ul` list like

```
<ul id="ulIdentificator"> 
    <li id="li0"></li>
    <li id="li1"></li>
    <li id="li2"><label id="label1"></label></li>   
</ul>
```

If I use jQuery like this

```
var htmlStr = $("#li2").html();
```

The result will be only string that contains label tag `<LABEL id="label1"></LABEL></li>` I need to get Html string that contains this `<LI id="li2"><LABEL id="label1"></LABEL></LI>`

Comment: Next jquery question after your was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917040/can-i-get-the-full-html-represenation-of-an-htmlelment-dom-object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [second OuterHTML technique](http://ivorycity.com/blog/2009/08/18/3/) Andres mentions (from the Web Architects' Blog) works on all browsers, so it's probably a better choice. The basic idea is that you can get an element's outer HTML by making it another element's innerHTML:

```
var outerHtml = $("<div/>").append($("#li2").clone()).html();
```

There's only one slightly tricky bit - make sure to `clone` your original element, so you don't remove it from the DOM.

If you do this often or want to do this to arrays of elements, it's probably worth following the linked example and make a little plugin to do this.

Comment: +1 very good answer. But in [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995760/in-jquery-are-there-any-function-that-similar-to-html-or-text-but-return-the/5314397#5314397) you have you have the same technique with also a solution for a problem with **IFrames**.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a small jQuery plugin with proposed method from Jeff Sternal:

```
// jQuery plugin 'htmlWithParent'

jQuery(function($) {

  $.fn.htmlWithParent = function() { return $j("<div/>").append($j(this).clone()).html(); };

});
```

and use this small cutom plugin, for example:

```
var htmlCode = $("<p><span>Helo world!</span></p>");

// Return only child nodes: <span>Helo world!</span>
var output1 = $(htmlCode).html();

// Return whole HTML code (childs + parent): <p><span>Helo world!</span></p>
var output2 = $(htmlCode).htmlWithParent();
```

Very useful method. ;)

Comment: Thanks. ;) I always make small custom jQuery plugins. Less code, more transparent.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery [OuterHTML](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/) , [OuterHTML II](http://ivorycity.com/blog/2009/08/18/3/)

Comment: The OuterHTML II technique is so simple, it's worth reproducing in the body of your answer.

Comment: Ok, this is the right answer, but I will accept it if you add some examples not just 2 links, for other SO folks to see it here.