# Can I get the full HTML representation of an HTMLElement DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm using jquery to parse some HTML, something like:

```
$(html).contents().each(function(){
  var element = this.tagName;
  ...
```

I can access the tagName, children, parent... using the DOM or the more friendly jQuery functions.

But at one point a need the whole HTML of the current element (not what `innerHTML` or `.html()` return) and I can't figure out a one liner to get it (I always  could attach the tag and the attributes manually to the innerHTML).

For example:

```
<a href="link">Link</a>
```

The `innerHTML` is `Link` but I'm looking for the whole `<a href="link">Link</a>`

does that oneliner exists?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763479/how-to-get-the-html-for-a-dom-element-in-javascript

Comment: Thank you!, I don't know how I could find that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this guy has a pretty nifty solution using jQuery: [outerHTML](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

just saw the anwser for this on the other thread :D

[outerHTML](http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/)

[outerHTML 2](http://ivorycity.com/blog/2009/08/18/3/)