# jQuery get html of container including the container itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i get the html on '#container' including '#container' and not just what's inside it.

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="one">test 1 </div>
 <div id="two">test 2 </div>
 <div id="three">test 3 </div>
 <div id="four">test 4 </div>
</div>
```

I have this which gets the html inside #container. it does not include the #container element itself. That's what i'm looking to do

```
var x = $('#container').html();
$('#save').val(x);
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/58/

Comment: you could put container inside another container and get that containers html... but that seems a little hacky.   perhaps if we knew a little more about the problem, we could come up with a workable solution?  what are you doing with a text area full of html?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get selected element's outer HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html)

Answer (score 176, accepted):

If you wrap the container in a dummy `P` tag you will get the container HTML also.

All you need to do is

```
var x = $('#container').wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
```

**Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/rzfPP/68/**

To `unwrap()`the `<p>` tag when done, you can add

```
$('#container').unwrap();
```

Comment: @mc10 we can simply use clone() and you will not have to worry about extra elements created.  `var x = $('#container').clone().wrap('<p/>').parent().html();`. The idea of wrap is great and allot less complicated then most of the solutions provided.

Comment: Firefox issue is out-of-date so I suggest to vote up @MikeM answer because it's in pure JS.

Comment: Why a `<p>` tag? Wouldn't a `<div>` make more sense?

Answer (score 151):

```
var x = $('#container').get(0).outerHTML;
```

**UPDATE** :  This is now supported by Firefox as of FireFox 11 (March 2012)

*As others have pointed out, this will not work in FireFox.  If you need it to work in FireFox, then you might want to take a look at the answer to this question : 
[In jQuery, are there any function that similar to html() or text() but return the whole content of matched component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995760/in-jquery-are-there-any-function-that-similar-to-html-or-text-but-return-the/995796#995796)*

Comment: This works in Firefox, and it's better than the accepted solution as of now.

Comment: this is an elegant way to do that, 
better then the accepted answer which was just a dirty hack

Comment: This is perfect.

Comment: this is the perfect answer because wrapping the parent tag with div or p is bad idea. may be your css will break. specially when you are using bootstrap (e.g form-row). hence this answer is quite good.

Answer (score 110):

I like to use this;

```
$('#container').prop('outerHTML');
```

Comment: This seems like the best solution to me, requires no dom manipulation, or pseudo dom manipulation (the wrap methods). And the jquery object already has the property.

Answer (score 73):

```
var x = $('#container')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Firefox issue is out-of-date so I suggest to vote up this answer.

Comment: Using .clone() works, but this is much cleaner, imo. The accepted answer creates new elements in the DOM = bad.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('#container').clone().wrapAll("<div/>").parent().html();
```

Update: outerHTML works on firefox now so use the other answer unless you need to support very old versions of firefox

Comment: outerHTML property does not work on Firefox so you need to do it with clone

Answer (score 2):

Oldie but goldie...

Since user is asking for jQuery, I'm going to keep it simple:

```
var html = $('#container').clone();
console.log(html);
```

[Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/962ausaf/4/)

Comment: This does not help in retrieving the html of the container itself. It does not even return html code. I can see that it may be practical to access the target node via clone to avoid modifying the dom, but then it would be good to mention why you use this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.outerHtml = function(){
    if (this.length) {
        var div = $('<div style="display:none"></div>');
        var clone =
        $(this[0].cloneNode(false)).html(this.html()).appendTo(div);
        var outer = div.html();
        div.remove();
        return outer;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

from http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-getting-html-and-the-container-element-12-1-2010

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = $($('div').html($('#container').clone())).html();
```

Comment: You are creating 3 jquery objects in one statement. Although it works, it's an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

[Firefox doesn't support outerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox), so you need to [define a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700870/how-do-i-do-outerhtml-in-firefox/3819589#3819589) to help support it:

```
function outerHTML(node) {
    return node.outerHTML || (
        function(n) {
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.appendChild( n.cloneNode(true) );
            var h = div.innerHTML;
            div = null;
            return h;
        }
    )(node);
}
```

Then, you can use outerHTML:

```
var x = outerHTML($('#container').get(0));
$('#save').val(x);
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple solution with an example :

```
<div id="id_div">
  <p>content<p>
</div>
```

Move this DIV to other DIV with id = "other_div_id"

```
$('#other_div_id').prepend( $('#id_div') );
```

Finish

Comment: The OP is requesting the raw HTML represented by a jQuery object, where this method moves a jQuery object from one place to another.