# IE7/8 + <time> tag + jQuery .clone() =?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I'll preface this by saying that I already solved this issue by fundamentally changing my approach. But in the process of solving it, I put together a test case that fascinates and vexes me.

I have a string returned from an AJAX call. The string contains HTML, most of which is useless. I want one element from the string (and all its children) inserted into the DOM. A simulation of this is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>wtf?</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var markup = '<div class="junk"><div class="good"><time datetime="2013-03-29">March 29, 2013</time></div></div>',
                output = $(markup).find('.good').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html();

            $('body').append(output);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

I have a hosted copy of this file up here: http://alala.smitelli.com/temp/wtf_ie.html (won't be up forever).

What this *should* do is extract the `.good` div and the child `<time>` element, then insert them into the body. I do `.wrap().parent()` to extract the element I selected in addition to its children (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459398/jquery-get-html-of-container-including-the-container-itself)). The `.clone()` and `.html()` are contrivances that demonstrate the problem.

To the user, it should show today's date. And it works in Chrome, Firefox, IE9, etc.:

```
March 29, 2013
```

But in IE7 and 8, the displayed text is:

```
<:time datetime="2013-03-29">March 29, 2013
```

The opening `<` is shown, and a colon has somehow been inserted. The closing `</time>` tag looks unaffected, and is not shown escaped.

What's going on here? Is this some sort of bug, or an expected behavior? Where is the colon coming from?

**EDIT:** As far as suggestions to add `document.createElement('time')` or html5shiv, neither of those seemed to change the behavior.

Comment: That is an HTML5 feature. I believe you'll need to use the html5shiv library to allow older browsers to support it

Comment: I'm surprised to find that adding `document.createElement('time')` doesn't fix it, at least not on IE7: http://jsbin.com/ifoxed/1 I was all ready to post that as an answer, but...

Comment: It appears to work in IE9's IE7/8 mode, but i don't have a true version to test it with.

Comment: @KevinB: I do. It doesn't. :-(

Comment: @KevinB Yeah, document.createElement('time') did not help. I will amend the question to say I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Very** much to my surprise, I find that if I remove jQuery from the equation in terms of actually parsing the markup, the problem goes away (on both IE7 and IE8), even without `createElement('time')` or a shim/shiv:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>wtf?</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var div, markup, output;

          markup = '<div class="junk"><div class="good"><time datetime="2013-03-29">March 29, 2013</time></div></div>';

          div = document.createElement('div');
          div.innerHTML = markup;

          output = $(div).find('.good').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html();

          $('body').append(output);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body></body>
</html>
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ifoxed/7) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ifoxed/7/edit)

The change there is that I just use the browser's own handling of `innerHTML` and a disconnected `div` to parse `markup`, rather than letting jQuery do it for me.

So I'd have to say this may be a problem with jQuery's handling of HTML fragments on older browsers without support for HTML5 elements. But that would be a significant claim, and significant claims require significant evidence...

But if I change these lines:

```
div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = markup;

output = $(div).find('.good').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html();
```

to:

```
div = $(markup);
output = div.find('.good').clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html();
```

I get the problem (on both IE7 and IE8): [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ifoxed/9) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ifoxed/9/edit)

So it does start seeming like a jQuery issue...

Comment: Good work :) I had a feeling that once you confirmed the html5shiv library didn't work, it had to do with jQuery's methods in some way (for whatever reason). I wish I could've tested more with native browsers

Comment: @Ian: Thanks. Yeah, it's *really* handy. Means I have a lot of VMs lying around, but sometimes, it's useful. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'd use more VMs too, I just don't have enough memory on my computer (and too lazy to change numbers) to add specific ones for IE :( So in your latest edits, does it fix it if you add the `document.createElement("time")` before that code (just a feeble attempt)? If not, I smell a jQuery bug to report...

Comment: @Ian: No, it doesn't matter whether you do that nor not. Probably what jQuery's doing represents a trade-off -- lots of *other* things work that might not otherwise (table fragments, or the default value in a `select` [I recall that was a Safari thing], etc., etc.), but this doesn't. If that's the case, seems a reasonable trade-off. :-)