# Copy all identified class to another class

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I click on the map, I copy all classes from class `li class="salony" id="wojewodztwo-malopolskie"` into class `<div id="spisSalonow">`. It's works correctly.

How can I do that, when I choice **krakow** from `select`(selector),Should I copy all classes with name **krakow** `<div class="krakow">` into class `<div id="spisSalonow">`?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
    $("svg").delegate("*", "click", function(e) { 
        $('.st0').removeAttr('style');
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).css("fill", "#ff6600");
            //$('#spisSalonow').stop().slideDown("slow").css('opacity', '0').html($('#wojewodztwo-' + id).html()).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).slideDown(500);
            $('#spisSalonow').stop().slideDown("slow").css('opacity', '0').html($('#wojewodztwo-malopolskie').html()).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).slideDown(500);
    });

    $("select" ).change(function() {

        var allListElements = $(".krakow");
        $( "#spisSalonow > div" ).find( allListElements );
       var liczbaSalonow = jQuery('.' +$(this).val()).length;
       //alert(jQuery('.' +$(this).val()).length);


        $('#spisSalonow').stop().slideDown("slow").css('opacity', '0').html($('.' + $(this).val()).html()).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).slideDown(500);
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4q8ud1pw/1/)**

Comment: It's apparent you don't speak English native, but your question is unclear. Are you wanting to use the dropdown to add that class to all of the regions?

Comment: I reworded the question to improve it as its unclear now. Please make sure the question is right and make title more specific.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/4q8ud1pw/7/

Is this what you wanted?

Thanks to ([jQuery get html of container including the container itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459398/jquery-get-html-of-container-including-the-container-itself)) for showing me how to include the container.

```
$("select" ).change(function() {
    var html = '';
    $(".krakow").each(function(){
        html += $(this).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
    });        
    $('#spisSalonow').stop().slideDown("slow").css('opacity', '0').html(html).animate({opacity: 1}, 1000).slideDown(500);
});
```