# how to get the full html element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all full element using class

```
<div class="number">one</div>
<div class="address">addr1</div>
<div class="number">twod</div>
```

I want what are all the div having class name  **number**, I want output full content with tags one by one using foreach statement. The expected output is like below

```
<div class="number">one</div>
<div class="number">two</div>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: Your question might be unclear, but what have you tried already since you were talking about `foreach`?

Comment: have you even attempted to write any jquery to solve this..?

Comment: Explain more on same @shamugam s

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but what's the issue with just `$('.number')`?

Comment: what are you trying to say...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459398/jquery-get-html-of-container-including-the-container-itself

Comment: Not clear. do you want $('.number, .address').each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML)
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.number, .address').each(function() {
  console.log(this.outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="number">one</div>
<div class="address">addr1</div>
<div class="number">twod</div>
```