# Convert string to HTML object error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try convert simple string to `HTML object` for process it with `jQuery`.
My code:

```
var old_code_text =  $(invoice_template_id).html();
console.log("old text ="+old_code_text);
old_code_text=$(old_code_text);
console.log("old text2 ="+old_code_text.html());
```

My first alert show me:

```
old text =<div id="template_invoice">
  <div id="first_head">
    <div id="logo_invoice">
        <img src="../../../images/invoice_logos/logo912131214.PNG" width="200px">
    </div>
    <div id="main_header_info">
....
....
  </div>
</div>
```

But my second alert show me :

```
old text2 =
<div id="first_head">
    <div id="logo_invoice">
        <img src="../../../images/invoice_logos/logo912131214.PNG" width="200px">
    </div>
    <div id="main_header_info">
    ....
```

Then I use `old_code_text` like it:

```
   old_code_text.find("#product_invoice_table tbody").empty();
```

I dont understand  where is div with id **template_invoice**? 
When I parse string this div always deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery get html of container including the container itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459398/jquery-get-html-of-container-including-the-container-itself)

Answer (score 0):

***wrap the container in a dummy p element tag and you will get the container HTML also***

```
var old_code_text = $("#template_invoice").wrap("<p/>").parent().html()
console.log("old text ="+old_code_text);
```